# Contractions with verbs preceded by "de" when there's a direct object pronoun

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, contractions, de

Would you say "N'oubliez pas *de le* porter" or "N'oubliez pas *du* porter" when "le" is a direct object pronoun for "le chapeau"?

Answer (score 1):

**La contraction de le = du n'est valable que pour les articles :**

> L'attaque du train postal = *de le* train postal

Idem pour *des = de les* :

> L'arrivée des voitures = *de les* voitures

Idem pour *au = à le*, et *aux = à les*

> Je vais au Touquet = *à Le* Touquet
>
> Je vais aux États-Unis = *à les* États-Unis

**Elle n'est pas valable pour les pronoms:**

> N'oubliez pas de le porter.
>
> N'oubliez pas de les prendre.
>
> Pensez à le porter.
>
> Pensez à les voir.